# Can’t get the text to appear below the Image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the text appear below the image but it is not budging at all. My goal is it make the text appear below the image in the container

```css
  
.left-col p {
  text-align: justify;
  width: 300px;
}

.left-col img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 5%;
  width: 300px; 
  height: 130px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
 <h1>The 3 Column Layout</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="left-col">
  <img src="Cyber.jpg" width="200" height=150"/>
  <p>
   <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec iaculis neque nec luctus maximus. Donec eu eleifend libero, nec scelerisque metus. Morbi volutpat turpis pretium
   </p>
```

Comment: Why are you `absolute`ly positioning the image?

Answer (score 1):

In css there is use [ position absolute ] For the image and is not used in the text You must set the position in the image and the text or leave it to the default setting I deleted it from the image properties in css

```css
.left-col p{
    text-align: justify;
    width:300px;
}                           

.left-col img{
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 5%;
    width:300px; 
    height: 130px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header">
     <h1>The 3 Column Layout</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="left-col">
      <img src="Cyber.jpg" width="200" height=150"/>
             <p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec iaculis neque nec luctus maximus. Donec eu eleifend libero, nec scelerisque metus. Morbi volutpat turpis pretium </p>

    </body>
```

Comment: What did you change here? **Edit** your post and explain your answer. Thank you

Comment: In css there is no use [ position absolute ] For the image and is not used in the text You must set the position in the image and the text or leave it to the default setting I deleted it from the image properties in css

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using position absolute, remove it. Reason is that the element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element. So, you could of course mess with top, right and left values to make it work but it would not be responsive at all.
Read more about it here: [MDN Position CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

The default value of position is static, this way the elements renders in a specific order(its what you want, render img and p after).

This is the pen if you need:

```
<div class="header">
  <h1>The 3 Column Layout</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-col">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x150" width="200" height="150" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec iaculis neque nec luctus maximus. Donec eu eleifend libero, nec scelerisque metus. Morbi volutpat turpis pretium </p>
  </div>
</div>
         .left-col p{
                     text-align: justify;
                      width:300px;
                      }


        .left-col img{
                      width:300px; 
                      height: 130px;
                     }
```

Also, instead of setting width 300px to paragraph and img, you could set only one time to your .left-col div. I have also removed other properties that you were not using.

another note is that you forgot the " on height attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line 'position: absolute;' from CSS. Complete (close) the DIV and P tags. You may introduce '.container{...}' where you may position (or whatever) the image-and-text together. You may wish to use 'margin: 0;' to glue the text to the image. Good luck!